# Firebase dynamic links iOS app preview is shown even when disabled

Tags: ios, firebase, deep-linking, firebase-dynamic-links

We've successfully implemented firebase dynamic links in an iOS app, and disabled the app preview page by adding `efr=1` to our links.

This works fine when the dynamic link is opened from an external source like the browser, or a whatsapp message. What I mean when I say that it works fine, is that the app preview page is not shown and the user gets redirected to the app.

However, when we open the dynamic link from inside our app, the user gets redirected to the app preview page. For example, from an in-app message, a popup with a button, or an internal app chat.

Is this normal?, how can it be avoided?

Comment: Have you tried [debugging](https://firebase.google.com/docs/dynamic-links/debug) your dynamic links?

Comment: Thank you @RodrigoMata, that page looks quite new. I'll give it a try.

Comment: As per my observation, efr=1 only works for long dynamic links and not short dynamic links.